# How to test for the entry_id of a related entry?

Tags: templates, template-scripting

I need to do a check like this:

```
{if:elseif {related_entries id="privacy"}{entry_id}{/related_entries} == 48}
```

However, the template errors out when there is no related entry. How do I do this test properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the parsing of the related entry, if there's no related entry, your conditional will became this:

```
{if:elseif == 48}
```

As you can see, this doesn't make any sense. So, add quotation marks:

```
{if:elseif "{related_entries id='privacy'}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" == 48}
```

After the parsing of the related entry, if there's no related entry, your conditional you became this:

```
{if:elseif "" == 48}
```

And it'll work fine.

Comment: Doh! I was fixated on trying to figure out how to check for NULL. Your answer makes sense. Thanks.